# PHP can't connect to PostgreSQL with "permission denied" error with SELinux

Tags: php, access-control, selinux

My PHP app can connect when I turn off SELinux, but not with it on.

```
setenforce 0; curl -I http://domain.com; setenforce 1
```

Yields no errors in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. However, if I have it on, I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Permission denied. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I've tried

```
# restorecon -R -v /home/domain/public_html
#  chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /home/domain/public_html/
#  chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t /home/domain/public_html
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/home/domain/public_html(/.*)?"
# service httpd restart
```

With SELinux on, I can still do this:

```
# php -a
Interactive shell

php > $connection = pg_connect ("dbname=domain user=domain password=xxxxxx") or die(pg_last_error());
php > echo $connection;
Resource id #1
```

Here is the error from `/var/log/audit/audit.log`:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1404684735.513:97245): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=3594 comm="httpd" name=".s.PGSQL.5432" dev=xvde ino=2552 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=sock_file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1404684735.513:97245): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=b a1=7f40ae4fd640 a2=6e a3=0 items=0 ppid=26231 pid=3594 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2700 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

CentOS 6.5

Comment: As @oneiroi pointed out the most relevant information is missing: the type of SELinux error. If you can run it manually from a shell though it's probably got to do with the domain or role being applied to your Web server depending on how it is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! I found a solution here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=772084#c8

What I did was take the 2 lines that were written to audit.log, and piped them into `audit2allow`, which generates 2 files, a binary and a text. Then I imported that file into `semodule`. I don't understand the file however. Make sure you capture the httpd errors.

```
tail -2 /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
semodule -i mypol.pp # takes a while
```

The actual text file it generated was `mypol.te`

```
module mypol 1.0;

require {
        type httpd_t;
        type initrc_t;
        class unix_stream_socket connectto;
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t initrc_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

Comment: Ok all you have done here is create a new policy to allow the action to take please; I am not saying this is wrong. However BE VERY CAREFUL in what you allow in a policy and understand what it is you are allowing to take please, please

Comment: @Oneiroi Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @Chole SELinux is there to prevent "out of context" actions from occurring; sometimes it may be needed to write a new module to define contexts in which the program may work; these should be understood, for instance allowing httpd_t access to the passwd_file_t and shadow_t would be a very bad idea, piping from the audit.log into audit2allow has the potential to "bite you" is all I'm saying here.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try simply setting the SELinux policy boolean that allows httpd to make DB connections via:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

This worked for me.  You can check/verify that the setting is set by:

```
getsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db
```

which should return '... => on'

After that, if you tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log and re-attempt your operation, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

More information is needed:

You need to look at /var/log/audit/audit.log for the avc denials.

alternatively ensure you have the following installed

1. setroubleshoot-server
2. auditd
3. messagebus

The messages will appear in /var/log/messages

further reference: http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/7995.html

The reason your php interactive shell works is that it is running in your user context, where as your application is running with the apache context.

Comment: I suspect the problem will be to do with the HTTPD user/process having issues connecting to Postgres (ie its not a problem with the html files, rather with PHP's inability to call the database).  It looks like @Chloe is on the right track by looking at SELinux rules, but the wrong "branch" in that the failure is occuring with the connection to the Postfix service, not the Apache service.

Comment: I added the errors from `audit.log`. From the link, I installed `setroubleshoot`, but it won't start as a service: `setroubleshoot: unrecognized service`. `setroubleshoot-server: unrecognized service`. `No package auditd available.`

Comment: @chloe you need to `yum install setroubleshoot-server` first ;-) then restart messagebus if allready present